# IP Address secondary transpose

Tags: cisco, nat

I am bit new to cisco and I have assigned 5 static IPs to my serial interface 0/0. I have NATed email in via one of the secondary IPs to the server. However, when I try to send mail out it's sending as my primary IP Address. How can I transpose the secondary IP address I want to the email server?

```
Router(config)#do show run | include nat
 ip nat outside
 ip nat inside
ip nat inside source list 1 interface GigabitEthernet0/0 overload
ip nat inside source static tcp 172.16.0.30 25 2.2.1.2 25 extendable
ip nat inside source static tcp 172.16.0.30 80 2.2.1.2 80 extendable
ip nat inside source static tcp 172.16.0.30 443 2.2.1.2 443 extendable
ip nat inside source static tcp 172.16.0.21 80 2.2.1.3 80 extendable
ip nat inside source static tcp 172.16.0.21 443 2.2.1.3 443 extendable
ip nat inside source static tcp 172.16.0.5 443 2.2.1.3 443 extendable
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One-to-One Nat is needed... so, you'll need to make sure that you create:

```
 ip nat inside source static 172.16.0.30 2.2.1.2
```

You'll also want to remove your PAT translation

```
ip nat inside source static tcp 172.16.0.30 25 2.2.1.2 25 extendable
ip nat inside source static tcp 172.16.0.30 80 2.2.1.2 80 extendable
ip nat inside source static tcp 172.16.0.30 443 2.2.1.2 443 extendable
```

Then you'll need to create an access-list to only allow the ports you want to go out and come in